# Not able to run Spring JUnit tests with second data source

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-bean

I am using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to run my integration tests. I had to use two data sources in my Spring Boot REST web service because I want to use different database users for Liquibase and Application queries. When I run the test, the second datasource is not getting created.

Following is my test code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class DomainServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateDomain() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Following is my datasource instantiation

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties, NileRegistrarProperties nileRegistrarProperties) {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUsername() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
        }
        if (dataSourceProperties.getPassword() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
        }

        //MySQL optimizations, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource".equals(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", nileRegistrarProperties.getDatasource().isCachePrepStmts());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", nileRegistrarProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSize());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", nileRegistrarProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSqlLimit());
        }
        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource liquibaseDataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase Datasource");
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        // Close all connections after liquibase operation is complete.
        config.setMinimumIdle(0);
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUsername() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", liquibaseProperties.getUser());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
        }
        if (dataSourceProperties.getPassword() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", liquibaseProperties.getPassword());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
        }

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("liquibaseDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                     LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

        // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());

        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");

        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

Following is the error message.

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed;
```

When I use single data source, everything is working is as expected.

Comment: I just realized data source is becoming h2 DB during test and that my LiquibaseProperties file is not initialized.

Comment: Why do you not use application.properties for your datasource configuration?

Comment: @RahulSharma I am using application.yml only for config. Are you talking about using in Test cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a similar project, where I have two datasources. Here is what I do,
`datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName
 datasource.primary.username=username
 datasource.primary.password=password`

Similarly for second datasource,
`datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName
 datasource.secondary.username=username
 datasource.secondary.password=password`

And in config class do just,

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "secondaryDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Wherever I need a datasource, I just autowire it like:

```
public void setJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondaryDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Note: The datasource annotated `@Primary` will be injected if `@Qualifier` is not used while autowiring.

Testing is much simpler with this. If you want to use in memory database for testing (most common technique), just provide another set of properties, with url of the in memory database, which can be used by the test class

Comment: I did exactly like this already. But this will keep connection pool open even though I need liquibase connection only during application start.. ?

Comment: Does it matter? You are using it for your tests. It would automatically be closed once the tests finish.